# Play Framework Dependency Injection Template in Eclipse doesn't highlight

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, playframework, twirl

I'm refactoring my play framework project from static templates to dependency injectioned templates. In eclipse, when using static templates, it highlights ok

[image: Eclipse highlighting the code]

 
But when I try to inject an object through the constructor, it compiles and works but the icon changes and it clears all the red '@' characters for vars and fors, ifs

 
[image: Eclipse doesn't highlight code and file icon changes]

 
I've tried cleaning workspace, recompiling eclipse project via sbt, and other eclipse configs but without success.

sbt-plugin version is 2.6.13
sbteclipse-plugin version is 5.2.4
scala version is 2.12.4
eclipse version is 4.7.2

Comment: Please add the warning message that is displayed in the second screenshot for the first two lines to your question.

Comment: Invalid text string (@this(injectedObject:Object)
@(cssList:List[String])). But I think it's unrelated

Comment: I guess it's because the Eclipse plugin doesn't recognize the content type correctly by reading the beginning of the file. Does right-click on the file, _Open With > Other..._ and choosing the Play editor work as a workaround? Please report this issue to the vendor of the Play Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: I've tried the Open With choosing Play editor, still not working. I think i'll report to the plugin developer.